# Matlab's dwt2 in publication quality notation?

Tags: matlab, wavelets, publishing

I used Matlab's [`dwt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html)in my algorithm, what notation have you folks seen that describes the 4 resulting wavelets? How do I express `[cA,cH,cV,cD]` in a familiar notation? I am specifically targeting the Haar wavelet...